# (C / Linux) Issue using bin/sh shell via netcat- the printfs not appearing on screen until program ends

Tags: c, linux, netcat

I am accessing my linux box via netcat using bin/sh as my shell.  I coded a small program, extract below:

```
printf("Enter command to exec \n");

fgets(abc,128,stdin);

....
```

What is happening is that when I run the program within the shell over netcat, the "enter command to send to system" doesn't print until after I have actually exited the program.

It should be the first thing that appears on screen after ./program, and strangely it takes my input upon run as if skipping the printf command. My input gets sent to the system fine (and prints the output), but the screen is otherwise blank with no printfs I have coded appearing.

However, once I exit the program, all the printfs actually appear (as if buffered) before it return to the shell.  Any thoughts as to why this happens?  If there is more information you need just let me know and I will gladly update the thread.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a terminal `stdout` is usually line buffered, you have to either `fflush(stdout)` or a print a new line `'\n'` to see your characters printed.

On non interactive devices, streams are often full-buffered and you have to flush `stdout` to have your characters printed:

```
printf("Enter command to send to system \n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: hi, this is the actual code, sorry: printf("Enter command to exec \n"); I have updated the thread now, sorry about that.

Comment: YES! stdout flushing has worked- genius! I'll marks as answered after the time has run out, thank you.